# How do I add the MCSCM.dll dependency in a Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a visual basic project that uses some vendor dlls which in turn use the MCSCM.dll. The project produces a x86 binary with the code necessary to interact with the USB chip card programmer.

When I run the compiled executable on my 64 bit Windows 10 machine, I get this message:

`System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'MCSCM.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

My question is, how do I add the MCSCM.dll dependency in Visual Studio?

EDIT:

The card device is a SCR3310 Cloud 2700 R.

I've confirmed the vendor DLLs are 32 bit.

From what I've read so far, MCSCM.dll provides an MCard API used by the vendor DLLs.  From what I can see, they created a wrapper does some database calls after writing to the card using the MCSCM.dll library.  I don't know if this is a system library or if its third party and where I can obtain/import it from.  All posts are 10+ years old!  I cannot find the DLL in my windows installation or anywhere on the internet.

Below is the most relevant I've found so far:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6b3240c-3c0c-4217-86c6-fe6644f924d7/dllimport-unmanaged-code?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: What is MCSCM.dll? Do you know? I don't. If you don't know, finding out would be the first order of business, before posting here. If you do know, that is information that is relevant to your issue so it is information that must be included in your question. ALWAYS include ALL relevant information.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am not 100% sure what it is.  I read some posts indicating it provides the functionality required to use the card device with some references to it's api.  Please find my edit above & thanks for the reply.

Comment: [SCR3xxx_CLOUD_uTrust_Tools_INST_V1.3_WIN](https://scm-pc-card.de/index.php?page=download&function=show_downloads&lang=en&category_id=32&p=SCR%20uTrust%20%202700%20R&c=USB%20Port%20%20-%20USB%202.0&product_id=842). [Identiv SCR3310 CLOUD 2700 R driver](https://www.drivermax.com/SCR3310-CLOUD-2700-R-Identiv-USB-VID-04E6-PID-5813-01_05_00_03-2014-11-05-54699-driver.htm) `<=` I don't know if this site is reliable.